# How do I upload a file into github, upload, not pull, merge, rebase, add just literally upload?

Tags: git, deployment, github, upload

We deploy some scripts directory from github.

I have an automated process that generates one of the scripts every hour.

I need to upload that to github fork, essentially pull, merge -s ours, commit, then do a pull request to the primary repo but without actually having a local copy of my forked repo. I really don't need to merge I want my file to overwrite the file of the same name that's in the repo, then commit it on github.

Oh, and this has to be done from the Linux command line as it's part of an hourly cron job.

Comment: That kind of workflow defeats the purpose of git

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any local clone of that (forked) GitHub repo, then you would need to use the [GitHub API in order to update a file](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file).

You can use one of the [GitHub API libraries for that](https://developer.github.com/libraries/), on order to do essentially a:

> `curl -u USER:PASS https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/contents/a.txt --request PUT --data-ascii $'{"path": "a.txt", "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM=", "message": "hello"}'`